# How to leave a message for a github.com user

Tags: github

Need help on GitHub usage. I wonder if there is a way to communicate with a github.com user i.e. write the user a message when only username/id is given on their GitHub page? Does GitHub have this social feature?

Comment: Answering the question (since it is now closed): you can open an Issue, and hope for the repo owner to answer you.

Comment: See [Any way to contact a user on Github?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29197/any-way-to-contact-a-user-on-github), which is on-topic at WebApps.SE.

Comment: Looks more like a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) to me.

Comment: ***For the privacy conscious***: **To avoid a personal email from showing per *any* of the answers here**, Github users can go to **Settings->Emails** and check the box for **Keep my email address private**. Then, they must **use `git config user.email` or `git config --global user.email` to set their local *git* email to the Github private email address (<username>@users.noreply.github.com)** All of their commits - from then on - will include only the private "noreply" email. *Note that any prior commits/local repo commits with the personal email set will still show it.*

Comment: A lot of these answers suggest using the public email addresses used in git commits. However, because this is easily abused by spammers, it is only natural that many people would use a non-important email address such as noreply@example.com.

Comment: Feature request on the current official issue tracker: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/15580

Answer (score 431):

Although GitHub removed the private messaging feature, there's still an alternative.

GitHub host git repositories. If the user you're willing to communicate with has ever committed some code, there are good chances you may reach your goal. Indeed, within each commit is stored some information about the author of the change or the one who accepted it.

Provided you're really dying to exchange with user **user_test**

- Display the public activity page of the user: https://github.com/user_test?tab=activity
- Search for an event stating **"user_test pushed to [branch] at [repository]"**. There are usually good chances, they may have pushed one of his own commits. Ensure this is the case by clicking on the "View comparison..." link and make sure the user is listed as one of the committers.
- Clone on your local machine the repository they pushed to: `git clone https://github.com/..../repository.git`
- Checkout the branch they pushed to: `git checkout [branch]`
- Display the latest commits: `git log -50`

As a committer/author, an email should be displayed along with the commit data.

**Note:** Every warning related to unsolicited email should apply there. Do *not* spam.

Comment: What is the user has no activity? I mean, simply created an account and never logged in again?

Comment: @mavili Because it may not be filled. See the question -> " when only user name/id is given on github page?"

Comment: @nulltoken I read your answer with tearful eyes. I can't believe this dream become true. tanks brother thanks ......

Comment: Chances are you will get a `username@users.noreply.github.com` address, in case someone really want to keep his email address private.

Comment: @tigrou That's the kind of email address sent by notifications. Not the one embedded in git commits.

Comment: @nulltoken Are you sure ? Take a look here : https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/

Comment: Ha! Indeed, if the commits are created with fake addresses, that won't help ;-). However, I can't remember having found even one leading OSS project with obfuscated emails in commits.

Comment: To just display the name and email you could do `git log --pretty="%an: %ae" -n 1` which will display something like `Author Name: email@domain.com`

Comment: Or check his/her website.

Comment: I hope Github people can see this answer, and add the Messenger feature back.

Comment: Private message was a feature? Wow, I never even knew that was a thing back then...

Answer (score 413):

**This method was working as of Feb 2024**

1. Copy and paste the next line into your browser (feel free to
   bookmark it): https://api.github.com/users/xxxxxxx/events/public
2. Find the GitHub username for which you want the email. Replace the
   xxxxxxx in the URL with the person's GitHub username. Hit Enter.
3. Press Ctrl+F and search for “email”.

As suggested by [qbolec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575699/qbolec), the above steps can be done by using this snippet:

```html
<input id=username type="text" placeholder="github username or repo link">
<button onclick="fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username.value.replace(/^.*com[/]([^/]*).*$/,'$1')}/events/public`).then(e=> e.json()).then(e => [...new Set([].concat.apply([],e.filter(x => x.type==='PushEvent').map(x => x.payload.commits.map(c => c.author.email)))).values()]).then(x => results.innerText = x)">GO</button>
<div id=results></div>
```

Source: [Matthew Ferree @ Sourcecon](https://www.sourcecon.com/how-to-find-almost-any-github-users-email-address/)

Comment: In my case it does not contain an Email

Comment: This method does require that the user has some public activity

Comment: This is a method just to find the e-mail id of the person. OP is asking to send a direct message to the repository owner using the GitHub website itself. e.g. Twitter and Facebook both have the concept of direct messages. With your solution I'll ultimately have to use another e-mail client e.g. gmail, yahoo mail etc and compose a new email to send message to the found email id.

Comment: Why to make so much of effort just to get email id of the user. It is visible on the profile page of the user itself like [this](https://github.com/RyanFehr) below his profile picture.

Comment: Whoa, this answer is just a treasure for spammers... "How to find any github's user email adress"

Comment: Comment to @RBT post. Many users do not have email address on the profile page. Like this one https://github.com/lqbweb

Comment: @Maciej That user has a email address on his profile page, too!

Comment: The email address in this api is coming from the user's local git setup, not what they've set in Github. **Github just recently added an option, under Settings/Emails, to block commits that accidentally include an email address the user has marked as 'private'.** And, yes, the api-revealed content is only applicable to public repos; private repo data won't show.

Comment: @mailnull.com, is this valid?

Comment: this trick shows the github email which you can not deliver a message!

Comment: Wait. Github shows my email public-available over the API despite the fact that i hide it utilizing github-settings? This does not sound alright to me :O

- Update: as of 02.03.2019 this is not working for accounts i teste. Good.

Comment: @Gewure still worked for me, showed several emails, not just the one I was looking for.

Comment: @pbhj somebody shoul tell github, probably. this is a privacy-leak.

Comment: We are all connected at this point. There is no privacy on the internet.

Comment: Only contains users.noreply.github.com addresses in my case.

Comment: If your local git is configured to include your e-mail address in commits, and you commit to a public repo, is it a privacy leak that github's API aggregates the already public data and makes it... publicer?  I'm uncertain.

Comment: Firefox has an awesome built-in filter field when viewing JSON data.  Just open the URL provided, and type "email" into that field.  Voilà!

Comment: I mean if its a public repository and you included your email in a commit in this PUBLIC repository, thats not really a privacy leak imo. But you can try to correct me.

Comment: re "*Jan 2023*"; all I got was a @users.noreply.github.com. (email will bounce)

Answer (score 137):

Simply create a dummy repo, open a new issue and use @xxxxx to notify the affected user.

If user has notification via e-mail enabled they will get an e-mail, if not they will notice on next login.

No need to search for e-mail address in commits or activity stream and privacy is respected.

Comment: should be a higher voted answer.  Simple and to the point and, as you said, respects privacy.  ty.

Comment: And if the account doesn't have any activity on it, pretty much the only way to do it I can find.

Comment: I'm new to GitHub and have only used it to download others' code. How do you create a dummy repo? Sorry for the incredibly basic question.

Answer (score 67):

For lazy people, like me, a snippet based on [Nikhil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44229207/575699)

```html
<input id=username type="text" placeholder="github username or repo link">
<button onclick="fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username.value.replace(/^.*com[/]([^/]*).*$/,'$1')}/events/public`).then(e=> e.json()).then(e => [...new Set([].concat.apply([],e.filter(x => x.type==='PushEvent').map(x => x.payload.commits.map(c => c.author.email)))).values()]).then(x => results.innerText = x)">GO</button>
<div id=results></div>
```

Comment: This will give false hits if the user you searched for had merged a PR from another user. In this case, `commits` will be an array with both the author of the PR and the merger (user who merged the PR).

Answer (score 36):

Here is another way:

- Browse someone's commit history (Click `commits` which is next to branch to see the whole commit history)
- Click the commit that with the person's username because there might be so many of them
- Then you should see the web address has a hash concatenated to the URL.  Add **`.patch`** to this commit URL
- You will *probably* see the person's email address there

Example: `https://github.com/[username]/[reponame]/commit/[hash].patch`

Source: [Chris Herron @ Sourcecon](https://www.sourcecon.com/how-to-find-almost-any-github-users-email-address-2-0/)

Comment: To avoid a personal email from showing this way, Github users can go to **Settings->Emails** and check the box for **Keep my email address private**. Then, they must **use `git config user.email` or `git config --global user.email` to set their local *git* email to the Github private email address (<username>@users.noreply.github.com)** All of their commits - from then on - will include only the private "noreply" email. *Note that any prior commits or local repo commits with the personal email set will still contain the real email address.*

Comment: It still works, thanks.
I hope, spammers will not abuse that feature.

Answer (score 34):

Github said on April 3rd 2012 :

> Today we're removing two features. They've been gathering dust for a while and it's time to throw them out : Fork Queue & Private Messaging

[Source](https://github.com/blog/1091-spring-cleaning)

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Look below for updated answers.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the removal of the *github messaging service*, usage was often not necessary due to many githubbers communicating with- and advocating [twitter](https://twitter.com/).

The **advantage** is that there is:

- full transparency
- better coverage
- better search features for tweets
- better archiving, for instance by the US Library of Congress

It is probably no coincidence that stackoverflow doesn't allow private messaging either, to ensure full transparency. The entire messaging issue is thoroughly discussed on meta-stackoverflow [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user).

Comment: Ok, what about any way to publically message them?  For instance, I want to ask a question about how to do a certain thing, and the documentation provided is atrocious.  It would be helpful for them to respond not just to me, but anybody trying to use their code.

Comment: You are always free to ask new questions should they fit the site. One criteria is that the question should interest others. If not, the documentation/project related questions are best passed through other channels

Comment: If you want to ask a question/report something about his/her project - simply open an "issue" in github and discuss

Comment: Came here wanting to message someone who doesn't have a project -_-

Comment: That's a sad state of affairs though. For me, Twitter is anything but a good platform.

Comment: @jitbit but what if the issues are disabled? And spamming in commit diffs is no good.

Comment: twitter is bad for real communication because 140 char limit.

Comment: This does not really help if there is no twitter listed on their profile page.

Comment: Gitter.im is great when devs are using it.

Comment: Comment to @jitbit post. Someone's question to the author does not always fit to opening an "issue" in github.

Comment: Not very helpful, I don't use Twitter because it's a disrespectful privacy-invasive platform, and there's no other way provided to contact said user. A better solution is to create a private repo specific to the user you're messaging and then use issues to create discussion threads with them. (at least this gives me a reason to create a repo for Microsoft to invade on)

Comment: twitter is the poster-child for dysfunctional communication.

Comment: @My1 `"twitter is bad for real communication because 140 char limit"` - then it has become better for that - Twitter increased the limit to 240 chars recently ;)

Comment: it's iirc not even that recetly lol. @Programmer

Comment: @My1 yeah, it was already a year ago or so …

Comment: "Don't you mean using "X"????  [ha ha]

Answer (score 1):

> Does GitHub have this social feature?

If the [commit email is kept private](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address#about-commit-email-addresses), GitHub [now (July 2020) proposes](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-22-users-and-organizations-can-now-add-twitter-usernames-to-their-github-profiles/):

> ### Users and organizations can now add Twitter usernames to their GitHub profiles

> You can now add your Twitter username to your GitHub profile directly from your profile page, via profile settings, and also the REST API.
>
> We've also added the latest changes:
>
> - Organization admins can now add Twitter usernames to their profile via organization profile settings and the REST API.
> - All users are now able to see Twitter usernames on user and organization profiles, as well as via the REST and GraphQL APIs.
> - When sponsorable maintainers and organizations add Twitter usernames to their profiles, we'll encourage new sponsors to include that Twitter username when they share their sponsorships on Twitter.

That could be a workaround to leave a message to a GitHub user.

Comment: But what if direct message is personally disabled? Kinda fair though, because then the developer can decide whether to be contacted instead of Github.

Comment: @KevinCrans Yes, I suppose that is the idea: put the user back in control of whether they want to be contacted or not.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution that worked for me very well is just to put the username of that particular user or repository link of corresponding user!

```html
<input id=username type="text" placeholder="Github Username or Repo link">
<button onclick="fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username.value.replace(/^.*com[/]([^/]*).*$/,'$1')}/events/public`).then(e=> e.json()).then(e => [...new Set([].concat.apply([],e.filter(x => x.type==='PushEvent').map(x => x.payload.commits.map(c => c.author.email)))).values()]).then(x => results.innerText = x)">GO, Get email!</button>
<div id=results></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use (and abuse) Private Vulnerability Reporting (Security Advisories)**

This feature was originally introduced to allow safely reporting security issues with a repository: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/security-advisories/guidance-on-reporting-and-writing/privately-reporting-a-security-vulnerability

This feature requires per-repository opt-in, and will therefore not be possible for the vast majority of repositories.

However, if you wish to allow yourself to be privately contacted, a natural convention would be to enable security advisories in your own:

- "home repository" `https://github.com/<username>/<username>`, e.g. https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli
- github pages home repository `https://github.com/<username>/<username>.github.io` e.g. https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io

To enable those:

- click the security tab of the repository: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli/security
- Enable vulnerability reporting
- Private vulnerability reporting -> Enable

Once this is enabled, when other users visit: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli/security they will see:

- a "Report a vulnerability button".
- a list of existing vulnerabilities

It is currently very confusing that if your a logged in as the owner, you do not see this page, but you can confirm by visiting the page logged off on a private tab.

Once a vulnerability is opened, it acts basically as a private GitHub issue, where both users can comment to communicate.

The repo owner can then decide to publish the vulnerability publicly at any time, at which point it will appear  on the list of vulnerabilities of the repository.

Once published, it becomes impossible to comment on the vulnerability however. But the repo owner can still edit the report title and body details.

For a casual not really a vulnerability conversation this requires:

- setting a dummy affects/fixed version. 0/1 will do just fine
- not request a CVE to not make GitHub admins mad at you, as apparently this opens a review on GitHub's side

In summary, this is too much work for the vast majority of users, and usage for private messaging will be rare. Opt-in is inevitable however for privacy control even if something more dedicated comes some day, so it will always be niche no matter what. But still, it's one way. I've enabled it on my home repos.

Answer (score 0):

Use the github api to fetch user details and more. Using Python:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>',
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

If it's not in the user data, use the commit api:

```
response = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits', headers=headers).content)
print(response[0]) # just get first if only one dev
```

To get a auth token, go to User-Settings->'Developer Settings'->'Personal Access Tokens', then create a token and insert into python script.